# Is there a design by contract framework for php?

Tags: php, design-by-contract

Is there a framework or library for php that will help me implement design by contract in my applications?

In the best case it would use javadoc like annotations in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've started work on a design-by-contract project [PHP-Contracts](https://gitorious.org/higher-order-php/php-contracts)

There are a few blog posts about the subject as well:

- [Towards a style of contract programming](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2010/07/13/towards-a-style-of-contract-programming/)
- [Design by contract in PHP with assertions](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/06/05/design-by-contract-in-php-with-assertions/)

Comment: What you did there looks nice. Maybe I will help in the development.

Answer (score 1):

New DbC framework for PHP based on Aspect-Oriented Programming: https://github.com/lisachenko/php-deal

```
/**
 * Simple trade account contract
 */
interface AccountContract
{
    /**
     * Deposits fixed amount of money to the account
     *
     * @param float $amount
     *
     * @Contract\Verify("$amount>0 && is_numeric($amount)")
     * @Contract\Ensure("$this->balance == $__old->balance+$amount")
     */
    public function deposit($amount);

    /**
     * Returns current balance
     *
     * @Contract\Ensure("$__result == $this->balance")
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getBalance();
}
```

Comment: I understand that AOP is different to Design by Contract. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Would it be something like http://code.google.com/p/addendum/?

Comment: That takes care of the annotations, but is not offering a design by conract solution.